# If a Rails model has_many children, how do I store the id of the first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I'm new to Rails, so it's possible I'm overlooking something simple.  I have a Rails model called a story.  Each story has_many segments, and each segment belongs_to a story.  I use the same form to create both the story and its first segment by using a fields_for section of the form and setting the story model to accepts_nested_attributes_for :segments.  I am currently able to use the form to create both a story and a segment simultaneously.

The problem is that each story also needs to store the id of its first segment, but when I'm saving the story, the segment hasn't yet been saved, so it doesn't yet have an id to store in the story, and I haven't been able to find a handle for the segment after the form is submitted so that I can save the segment first before the story is created.  So my question is **how do I save a record of the first_segment_id inside the story?**

The following code may be relevant:

*in app/models/story.rb*

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :segments_attributes
    has_many :segments
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :segments
end
```

*in app/models/segment.rb*

```
class Segment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :words
  belongs_to :story
end
```

*in app/views/stories/*_ *form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(@story) do |f| %>

  #...stories fields...

  <%= f.fields_for :segments do |segment_form| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= segment_form.label :words %><br />
      <%= segment_form.text_area :words %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

*in app/controllers/stories*_ *controller.rb*

```
  def new
    @story = Story.new

    @segment = @story.segments.build

    # If I try replacing the above with @segment = @story.segments.create
    # then I get the error message "You cannot call create unless the 
    # parent is saved," which is problematic because I need to find some way 
    # to get the id of @segment to save in the parent story, but the segment
    # won't have an id until after it has been saved.  

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @story }
    end
  end

  def create
    @story = Story.new(params[:story])

    #  @segment.save
    #  @story.first_segment_id = @segment.id
    #  If I uncomment the above two lines, I get the error message 
    #  "undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass".  It appears that 
    #  @segment hasn't been passed from the "new" method above to 
    #  this method as a handle of the first segment created, so I'm not 
    #  able to save it to get an id for it before saving the story.  
    #  Is there some way to save the segment here?

    respond_to do |format|
      #...if @story.save...
    end
  end
```

*The params hash submitted by the form looks something like:*

```
{ "story"=>{ Various_other_story_fields,
 "segments_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"words"=>"dfsdsa"}}},
 "commit"=>"Create Story"}
```

Is there a way to save the first segment's id in the story?  I think perhaps I need to add a before_create inside my story model instead, but I'm not sure how do to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this differently, adding a numeric `sort_order` column to `Segment` so that you're not relying on `Segment` ids to determine what order they go in. Then you can define something like the following on your `Story` model rather than explicitly referencing the first segment in the database:

```
def first_segment
   segments.order(:sort_order).first
end
```

If you're certain you need to store the first segment ID in the story, you can `.save` the story so that it knows its ID, saves its children, and knows their IDs. Something like:

```
def create
   @story = Story.new(params[:story])
   @story.save # Save the story and its child segment so that they both have IDs
   @story.first_segment_id = @story.segments.first.id
   @story.save
   ...
end
```

Comment: I don't think the second way you suggest will work.  It tries to get the id of the segment before that segment has been saved, at which point the segment doesn't have an id.

Comment: +1 The first way you suggest could work, and it has directed me toward the even simpler method of just using segments.first (because the first one created should always be the one with the first id, and in my case, the order doesn't change)...I can't believe I've been overlooking that for days, but then I am *very* new to Rails.  However, the thing that concerns me about calling the .first method every time is that it's inefficient. It is something that will be done quite frequently, so if possible I'd still like to find a way to store the individual id.

Comment: Sorry, I should've made it clearer that that code is intended to run after you've already saved the story (without a foreign key yet) and the segment once. But yes, using the IDs as a sort can work as long as you don't need to change the sorting. I don't think that will be inefficient: I suspect most DB servers are smart enough to just jump to the first record in the clustered index that matches the foreign key.

Comment: To make that second code block run automatically after the story is saved, where would you place it?  Toward the end of the create method in the controller?  In an after_save callback in the model?

Comment: Yes, that works.  I'm quite surprised to find that you can save a story a second time without having to pull it from the database again.  Saving it the first time seems to have populated the local variable with the segment id.  Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like:

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :segments_attributes
    has_many :segments
    has_one :first_segment
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :segments
end

def new
    @story = Story.new

    @segment = @story.segments.build
    @story.first_segment = @segment
    ...
```

You'll have to add story_id to your segment table.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly, first_segment would be its own model??  I'm not really getting a full picture of how it would relate to the other models.  Can you please be a bit more explicit?

Comment: It's a has_one relationship, so the foreign key is in the owned model (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association). Due to the way rails implements associations, what this does is just create a new relationship between the records in the db. The only caveat is that once the story is saved, Story#first_segment and Story#segments.first will have the same data but will NOT be the same object

Comment: Haha, the page you link to is all-too-familiar.  (I've been staring at it for most of today.)  +1 for suggesting a way that could work, but if possible I'd like to find a way that works without having to create an extra model.  I may need to update the segment, so storing them in two places is less than ideal.  Also, each segment has a fair chunk of text associated with it, so storing it in only one place would be best for memory.

Comment: You don't need to create a new model. first_segment uses your existing Segment model.